# recover Items in a users online archive from there recoverable items

Tags: powershell, email, office365, exchange-server

In exchange 365 is there a way to recover items in a user's online archive from their recoverable items? I know for the mailbox I can use PowerShell command `Restore-RecoverableItems`
once I am connected to exchange online Powershell. I can not figure out if there is a similar command for doing this from the Online archive.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up contacting MS on this and you can use the `Restore-RecoverableItems` command once you have the GUID for the online archive. To get the GUID I used powershell

```
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails Usermailbox | Select Name,ArchiveGuid
```

I put ARchiveGuid into a variable and then ran that against the restore

```
Restore-RecoverableItems -Identity "$GuidSource" -ResultSize "unlimited" -SourceFolder RecoverableItems  -FilterItemType Ipm.Note  -FilterStartTime "6/4/1989 01:23:00"
```

Hopefully, this helps someone else who runs into this issue.